# Is there any point in requesting traffic data in proximities smaller than 1km?

Tags: here-api

I already know from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893652/traffic-flow-request-in-here-api-returns-results-outside-of-the-proximity) I posted, that the the here traffic API has data in tiles 1x1 km. So my question is this: Is there any way that someone could get data in proximities smaller than that? (say 100m). Is there even any point in sending out requests with small proximities? If not why doesn't the API restrict you from doing so.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked this, but I assume that you receive all tiles that intersect the area within your radius. So giving a small radius which defines an area that is completely covered by a single tile would only return this tile, while a bigger radius will intersect multiple tiles and return all of them.

If you want to ignore everything outside of your radius, you can iterate over the geo-positions and keep only those entries within a specific distance to your center point.

To do this, add `&responseattributes=sh` in the traffic flow request to receive the road shape as a list of geo-positions (see [request example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/traffic/traffic-flow-shape-fc)).
The field 'SHP' then contains the positions of the traffic flow data as a list of latitude and longitude, from which you can keep only those entries which are within a given distance to your center point (using `H.geo.Point(lat, lng).distance(centerPoint)`).

In case of a very small radius you should consider to check the intersections of the shape lines rather than the shape points.

Comment: Hi, this souns promising, is there any documentation where I could read more about how this works in detail? What exactly is the "road shape" ?

Comment: Edited response and added a link to request documentation

Comment: Thank you, I'll let you know when I try this out