# Inaccuracies in retrieval of road functional class in proximity of a point

Tags: geolocation, here-api, traffic

As a way to meke it more interactive, I will use the demo from this page: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/traffic/traffic-flow-proximity-shape-fc

Here is an example of an API call:

https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?prox=51.2141%2C4.4551%2C10&locationreferences=shp&responseattributes=fc&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ

[image]

Response:

```
{
  "RWS": [],
  "MAP_VERSION": "",
  "CREATED_TIMESTAMP": "2020-05-28T12:05:18.000+0000",
  "VERSION": "3.1",
  "UNITS": "metric"
}
```

The result is empty, but clearly, S County Road 250 W is within the circle and I would expect that the request would return the functional class of this road.

Note that if I use TMC, then I will get a ton of information about roads/locations that are not in the circle.

*Am I doing something wrong? All I need are roads within the circle, and their functional class (ideally supplied with traffic information). Is that possible?*

Comment: See also this question, which is the other way around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893652/traffic-flow-request-in-here-api-returns-results-outside-of-the-proximity

Comment: It depends on whether Road is TMC or DLR. You're are making request with SH location reference, if road belongs to TMC then it will be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

API is giving correct response however the problem is, that even if you can specify 1 or 100 meters as radius the service really support only the smallest resolution of 1 km. This is due to how the data is stored in the service, which is tile based.

and each such a request is then converted to tiles - which have a predefined size. So a 100 meters request can end up in a tile of size 1x1 km easily. That is why you get traffic outside of a smaller proximity.

You can refer to Here Traffic API Documentation to get the response elements and meanings documentation.developer.here.com/pdf/traffic_hlp/6.0.85.0/Traffic%20API%20v6.0.85.0%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf. You can also go to `

> developer.here.com/documentation/versions

and download this file.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my questions. Could you clarify? If what you are saying is true, then I would get many RWs in my response, no? But the point is that I do not get a single one, although there are many roadways in the 1x1km area.. (i.e. `"RWS": []`) And second, if what you are saying is true and only tiles are considered, then what is the point of having the `proximity` resource?