# HERE Traffic API: How to extract flow data only for the given corridor

Tags: here-api

I've been trying to extract traffic flow data for a specific road segment using a very tight corridor definition, but this seems impossible because the Traffic API will return data for a 1x1 km segment. I didn't find this information anywhere in the official documentation, but it's been mentioned a couple of times on StackOverflow, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58952748/1420399

My function to retrieve the data (in Python):

```
def get_corridor_data(corridor_points, width):
    polyline = flexpolyline.encode(corridor_points)
    radius = int(width/2)
    response = requests.get(
        "https://data.traffic.hereapi.com/v7/flow",
        headers={"Content-Type": "*"},
        params={
            "apiKey": API_KEY,
            "in": f"corridor:{polyline};r={radius}",
            "locationReferencing": "shape"
        }
    )
    ...
```

I wanted to filter the received results by checking if the coordinates included in the `shape` data for each road fall within my specified corridor, but it doesn't seem to be working - multiple roads that are not within the corridor still have `shape` coordinates that fall within the corridor. It's unclear what the `shape` coordinates represent as this also doesn't seem to be documented.

How to properly filter the Traffic API results so that I only get relevant data - what actually fits within the specified corridor?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make additional route match POST request with parameter attributes=ROAD_GEOM_FCn(LAT,LON) (use your corridor_points as input parameters) utilize [Route Matching API v8](https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-matching/dev_guide/index.html) (RME) like:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://routematching.hereapi.com/v8/match/routelinks?routeMatch=1&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&attributes=ROAD_GEOM_FCn(LAT,LON)&apikey=***' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw 'LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
53.3737131,-1.4704939
53.3742428,-1.4677477
53.3745646,-1.467576
53.3758092,-1.4665675
53.3765066,-1.4645076'
```

In the response you can take whether LAT, LON of ROAD_GEOM_FCn or shape of each road link and compare them with shape of response of https://data.traffic.hereapi.com/v7/flow request.

How you can compare the coordinates? Like this:

All coordinates in Route Match response are rounded to 5 decimal digits therefore you can compare them like:

```
if abs(latRME - latTraff) <= 0.00001 and abs(lngRME - lngTraff) <= 0.00001: coordsAreEqual = true
```

With this comparison you can recognize which shapes belong to your corridor_points.